# Getting a 1004 Method range of object - 'Global' failed error

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,
I cant figure out what the issue here is. On the Set iterationCell line, I am getting a 1004 error.

```
Dim ri As Long 'row initial
Dim re As Long 'row end
Dim mergeRange As Range
Dim iterationCell As Range
ri = 1
re = 25
Set mergeRange = Range(Cells(1, ri), Cells(1, re))
Set iterationCell = Range(Cells(1, ri))
iterationCell.Value = "Iteration " & CStr(j)
```

I tried moving the set iterationCell above the mergeRange thinking that might be causing the issue, but it still give that error.

If I change it to "Set iterationCell = Range(Cells(1, ri), Cells(1, ri))" it seems to work, but I think its weird that range cant have a single cell value when everything I see online seems to indicate otherwise.sd

Comment: `Set iterationCell = Cells(1, ri)` You may also want to qualify all your `Range` and `Cells` with the worksheet.